# miktex problem building tex-format

Tags: miktex2.9

Hallo miktex specialists,

I came across the following problem with my miktex-installation (on my private computer, windows 10, maybe a problem concerning single-user vs. system-wide installation):

1. In building the tex-format from miktex-console in **admin-mode** the process stops complaining about missing font manfnt. See log-files below.
2. In **single-user** mode there is no problem in building the tex-format.
   The file manfnt.tfm is present at the appropriate place 
   *c:\Users..\AppData\Local\MiKTex\2.9\fonts\tfm\public\knuth-lib\manfnt.tfm*
   and it is re-created there if it was missing.
3. Deleting manfnt.tfm in c:\Users... or even the complete directory
   *C:\Users..\AppData\Local\MikTeX* and restarting 1. (in admin-mode!) building the format again fails, **but** the tfm-file is generated in the appropriate **single-user** place *c:\Users...* as given above.
4. Finally, after copying the file manfnt.tfm to the appropriate place in the system-wide installation directory *MikTeX2.9\fonts\tfm\public\knuth-lib\manfnt.tfm* the building of the format succeeds in admin-mode.
5. Here is my log-file to process 1.

> miktex-makefmt: warning: running with administrator privileges
>   Running miktex-tex.exe...
>   This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit) (INITEX)
>
> (D:/TeX/MiKTeX2.9/tex/plain/config/tex.ini
>
> (D:\TeX\MiKTeX2.9\tex/plain/base\plain.tex Preloading the plain format: codes,
>   registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,miktex-maketfm: warning: running with administrator privileges
>
> initexmf: warning: Option --admin should be specified when running this program with administrator privileges
>
> initexmf: warning: Option --admin should be specified when running this program with administrator privileges
>
> Making manfnt.tfm from D:\TeX\MiKTeX2.9\fonts/source/public/knuth-lib\manfnt.mf...
>
> Running miktex-mf.exe...
>
> miktex-mf: warning: running with administrator privileges
>
> This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit)
>
> (D:\TeX\MiKTeX2.9\fonts/source/public/knuth-lib\manfnt.mf
>
> Hex symbols [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
>
> Stick A's [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16]
>
> Kidney b

Here the log-file stops.
What puzzles me in this log-file is the *initexmf: warning: Option --admin should be specified when ...*. Running the miktex-console_admin.exe I don't see a way to give this option.

Thanks for help
Norbert Klingen

Comment: Add an issue to the miktex issue tracker.https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thanks, for the hint. But as I am a simple user of (La)TeX and not a developer GitHub does not seem the right place for me.

Comment: If MiKTeX has a bug the right place to report it for everyone is the issue tracker. Only the miktex maintainer can help you in such cases.

Comment: I posed this report on GitHub as proposed by Ulrike Fischer and therefore I think the topic should be closed here.

Comment: See https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/391 .